# Parse top-level value with Aeson

Tags: haskell, aeson

I'm trying to parse JSON values with Aeson and I have no problem (so far) parsing objects or arrays, but I can't get Aeson to parse JSON documents that are just strings.

As I understand, since RFC 7159 values are legal JSON documents, and Aeson supports that since 0.9.0.0 (I'm using 0.9.0.1), so it should work. For example, I'm wrapping an API that returns strings as top-level JSON documents for many of its calls, and would like to newtype those strings for some static typing safety:

```
newtype Bar = Bar String deriving (Eq, Show)
instance FromJSON Bar where
    parseJSON (String v) = pure (Bar $ T.unpack v)
    parseJSON _ = mzero
```

If I try to decode something:

```
decode "JustSomeRandomString" :: Maybe Bar
```

all I get is `Nothing` in return.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Of course, I could handle API calls that return strings as JSON documents without Aeson, but would like to keep things uniform!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `decode "\"JustSomeRandomString\"" :: Maybe Bar`

Comment: Can't believe I missed that, I just copied curl output from the console and worked with that. The API I'm using is broken, it doesn't wrap strings in quotes...